# Value of variable $*

Tags: linux, wildcard

I'm a newbie Linux user, and I have run into this problem.

If the following commands have been executed

```
set 10 20 30 40 50
shift
shift
```

how would I find the value of `$*`?

Comment: What do you mean, "find the value"?

Comment: sorry i shouldn't have said, "find" but rather "enter the value of $*"

 basically i want to find out given the commands that have been executed i need to get the value of $*.

Comment: I still don't understand.  After the commands you've shown `$*` is just `30 40 50`.

Comment: thats the answer i was looking for but i dont understand why $* is 30 40 and 50

Comment: ... did you read the documentation?

Comment: Probably you don't understand what shift does here.

Comment: See these examples: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/bash-shell-builtin-commands/

Comment: `$*` is equivalent to `$1c$2c…`, where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to find the value of `$*` is to echo it:

```
echo $*
```

Given the three steps shown, it will echo:

```
30 40 50
```

The value of `$*` without quotes is the same as the value of `$@` without quotes, and consists of all the positional arguments to the shell script, or the values set by a `set` command such as the one you showed (as modified by any subsequent `shift` commands).  With double quotes around them, `"$*"` represents a single string with all the positional parameters in it, but `"$@"` represents a number of strings, each one identical to a positional parameter.  It is the form that is more commonly correct.

You can see the difference between these forms with the `printf` command:

```
printf "%s\n"  $*
printf "%s\n" "$*"
printf "%s\n"  $@
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

You'd get more insight into them if you used:

```
set -- 10 '20 30' '  40  50  '
```

without any shifts, and then used the 4 `printf` commands:

```
printf "X%sX\n"  $*
printf "X%sX\n" "$*"
printf "X%sX\n"  $@
printf "X%sX\n" "$@"
```

The X's serve to mark the start and end of the values printed.  The output is:

```
X10X
X20X
X30X
X40X
X50X
X10 20 30   40  50  X
X10X
X20X
X30X
X40X
X50X
X10X
X20 30X
X  40  50  X
```

The relevant section of the Bash manual is [special parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters).

Answer (score 0):

From the `bash` man page:

> `set`:  Any
>                 arguments  remaining after the options are processed are treated
>                 as values for the positional parameters  and  are  assigned,  in
>                 order, to `$1`, `$2`, ...  `$n`.

And:

> `shift [n]`:
>                 The positional parameters from `n+1 ...` are renamed  to  `$1 ....`
>                 Parameters  represented  by  the  numbers  `$#` down to `$#-n+1` are
>                 unset... If `n` is not given,
>                 it is assumed to be 1.

So your `set` sets:

```
$1 = 10
$2 = 20
$3 = 30
$4 = 40
$5 = 50
```

And then the `shift` commands throw out `$1` and shuffle the other `$n` variables down by one.  You do it twice, so that leaves you with:

```
$1 = 30
$2 = 40
$3 = 50
```

You could just use: `echo $*` to see the output:

```
30 40 50
```

Answer (score 0):

its a bit odd ..... the question says , value of $* ...... well that stands for everything that was put into the command and hence was passed onto the posistional parameters .

the shift command will just push everything that was there in the original command line one place left .... so from 10 20 30 40 50 ..... after two sahifts (2 times push to the left) you have 30 40 50 now that can be accessed by specifying their position/occurence with a $ like $1 ... $2

```
$ set 10 20 30 40 50
$ shift 2
$ echo $*
30 40 50
```

to put it simply ....

if you want to access individual values .... just use $1 , $2 .... like wise , here $1 will have 30 and $2 will have 40.

of you want to know how many parameters you have use $#

```
$ echo $#
 3
```

does this help ?